# retaining UIAlertView delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have ARCfied simple wrapper (let's call it customAlert) over UIAlertView which have own delegates like

```
@protocol customAlert
-(void)pressedOnYES;
- (void)pressedNO
```

custom alert itself contains UIAlertView as a strong property and alertView.delegate = self; (customAlert is delegate of UIAlertView)

The issue I have - customAlert is deallocated when UIAlertView delegate's method being called.

f.e

```
customAlert *alert = [customAlert alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[alert show]; // it will call customAlert [self.alertView show]
```

customAlert will be deallocated on run loop, and next event (pressing UIAlertView button will be send to deallocated object)

I have to retain somehow customAlert object to avoid it (I can't use property of customAlert instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue you are facing, as an immediate fix, instead of keeping 'alert' as a local object, try declaring it as a strong property of the class.

But better keep 'customAlert' as subclass of 'UIAlertView' instead of having 'UIAlertView' as a property of customAlert.

An example of a custom alert class (Haven't added much comments. Code is simple and self descriptive).

**CustomAlert.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @protocol customAlertDelegate<NSObject>
    - (void)pressedOnYES;
    - (void)pressedNO;
    @end

    @interface CustomAlert : UIAlertView
    - (CustomAlert *)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
    @property (weak) id <customAlertDelegate> delegate1;
    @end
```

**CustomAlert.m**

```
#import "CustomAlert.h"

@implementation CustomAlert
@synthesize delegate1;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (CustomAlert *)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    if (self) {
        //Assigning an object for customAlertDelegate
        self.delegate1 = delegate;
    }

    return self;
}
//Method called when a button clicked on alert view
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex) {
        [self.delegate1 pressedOnYES];
    } else {
        [self.delegate1 pressedNO];
    }
}
@end
```

Your View controller with delegate methods

*ViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomAlert.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <customAlertDelegate>
@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)pressBtn:(id)sender
{
    CustomAlert *alert=[[CustomAlert alloc] initWithDelegate:self] ;
   [alert show];
}

- (void)pressedOnYES
{
    //write code for yes
}

- (void)pressedNO
{
    //write code for No
}

@end
```

Comment: so customClass : UIAlertView.. I will try

Comment: no, it's not about UIAlertView, the reason is - customAlert instance is deallocated. If customAlert instance is retained by someone else (f.e property "strong") sure it works

Comment: Ok, by 'alert', I meant customAlert. Anyways, hope everything works fine now.

Comment: yes.... but I want to create instance of customAlert f.e in -viewDidLoad without having "strong" property f.e [CustomAlert showWithDelegate:self];

Comment: Sorry for replying late, for declaring the alert as local variable, I'll add an UIAlertView SubClass for you to try, in the above answer.

Comment: You shouldn't retain (strong reference) a delegate otherwise you risk introducing retain cycles. e.g. `Object1` creates `alert` and sets `self` as delegate.. now `object1` retains `alert` and `alert` retains `object1` and neither is ever released.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find the error in code, please specify if anything is present.